# File size calculated incorrectly (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to determine the file size of image selected using UIImagePicker. My code is as follows:

```
func fileSizeOK(image: UIImage) -> Bool {

        let selectedImageData: NSData = NSData(data:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1)!)
        let selectedImageSize: Int = selectedImageData.length / 1024
        print("Image Size: \(selectedImageSize)KB")
        return true
}
```

I am getting 151KB reported as the file size. However the images actual file size is 103KB (I checked by opening the mail app and adding it as an attachment). What could I be doing wrong here?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `NSData` length is not equal to file size . Make good use of `NSFileManager`'s `attributesOfItemAtPath:`'s filesize property.

Comment: Are you using the exact same data? You are calculating the JPEG size in KB correctly. The only difference could be that you are encoding it differently somewhere else.

Comment: Also, edited image & original image from `UIImagePicker` could be different.

Comment: @Raptor - Are your sure about that? It would seem odd if the UIImageJPEGRepresentation excludes file header data as it wouldn't know how to read back the Jpeg data without it. Also, surely there is a way to tell the file size without having to write out the file.